# What is the best strategy for Real-time Live Streaming

Tags: video-streaming, streaming

I'm not referring to which transport technology (e.g WebRTC, Web Socket, standard HTTP etc.) is the best for real-time live streaming of Web Cameras, etc., but, the general strategy (*in terms of programming itself*).

In my testing, I found the best is to:

1. Just stream frame by frame (stream JPEG images directly) at least at 30ms/frame however this is quite bandwidth intensive. (Say each frame is 50kb average, for 1 second video that's 500kb, and thats about 30MB per minute so in an hour that would be 1.8GB give or take), solution maybe is not to use JPEG, but something like [AVIF image compression](http://%20https://netflixtechblog.com/avif-for-next-generation-image-coding-b1d75675fe4) which when I tested the size and quality is very optimal. It may bring down the bandwidth issue with frame-by-frame real-time streaming. **Summary for this approach is it is really real-time, fast and smooth but eats up bandwidth.**
2. I also tested with MJPEG (encoding frames first then sending it in chunks) -- container is AVI but images inside are compressed JPEG images. Framerate is smooth but local looback already have 1 second latency, so if this is going to be sent over the network (via UDP, TCP / HTTP / Websocket etc.), haven't tested but I assume it would add additional latency, say 1 second. I've researched on existing streaming, and found total latency is 3 seconds, so just about what I have now. **Summary for MJPEG, I don't suppose it saves bandwidth at all, since after all inside the AVI container it still JPEG images, what was saved was the number of network requests (not sure if that's even a plus)**
3. Finally, similar to the MJPEG approach, but use encoders/decoders like MPEG1, MPEG4, WEBM etc. will definitely save bandwidth due to better compression algorithm but will definitely add to the latency, since the MJPEG with just raw packing of JPEG inside a container, this approach will add additional CPU workload to process further compression. **So summary for this approach is it saves bandwidth but adds more latency.**

Given the 3 scenarios above, I would assume that the best strategy for real-time streaming is to not compress at all, the least is to compress in JPEG and pack the JPEG into a container (like 3-4 frames per pack) at 100 ms and stream that bytes into the network. **However for an expert in real-time streaming, what is the best strategy for Real-time Live Streaming?**

Answer (score 0):

An important concept to consider is congestion control. Your network will fluctuate, and you need to be able to respond to it. With everything you have proposed you have no way to measure backpressure, and then respond to it.

Web Socket, standard HTTP will operate pretty similarly, but WebRTC will perform dramatically better if you use it properly. WebRTC hasn't done anything new to solve this problem, but it uses the existing technology RTP/RTCP which allows senders and receivers to communicate about the state of the media transfer. The sender could adjust bitrate on the fly, or even change the coding complexity if the receiver requests that.

I don't have a good single document for all this, but the [rmcat requirements](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rmcat-cc-requirements-09) does a good job of explaining this!

All of these solutions you proposed above can be run over RTP, and you just need to evaluate your requirements and what you have available (bandwidth, latency etc..). But I think in the end any robust solution requires receiver feedback.

Comment: Yes, in fact you're right network will change, I think this is how adaptive bitrate streaming is about, but going back  to the root, so streaming Frame-by-Frame is not a good idea? I mean, I've been studying the binaries of media stream, in the end each frame is sent but the general approach is to put it in a container (either compressed or not) -- so my theory is if we can find a really good image compression like AVIF why not just send the frames (again regardless whether via UDP or TCP)